# SQL Case can't get rid of 0

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 2 columns. "Test" and Cust#. "Test" is populated with "Y" or "N". Cust# is populated with a customer number.

If the test is "Y" then cust# = a number. If "N", cust# = 0.

I don't want the "0" to return for my grid display. Here is one line I'm using...

```
(case when test = 'Y' then custno else '' end) Cust#
```

The "Else ' ' " still returns the "0", I've tried several different arrangements and cannot get a blank return rather than the "0' when test = "N".

Comment: Specify table data and accepted data

Comment: try cast(custno as varchar) within the case statement and see if that works.

Comment: This can be a problem with the display in your application, since it most likely inheriting a property that it has to display a number. Either change that or remove the `ELSE` from the `CASE`.

Comment: Test is varchar, Cust# is integer. Cust# always has a number, most are 0. For the grid display, I don't want the 0 displayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `Cust#` is a number, then your choices for output are a number or `NULL`.  So, go for `NULL` and just leave off the `else`:

```
(case when test = 'Y' then custno end) as Cust#
```

If you really, really want a blank, then convert the value to a string:

```
(case when test = 'Y' then cast(custno as varchar(255)) else '' end) as Cust#
```

Comment: YUP, the cast done it, thanks to both of you (Doolius & Gordon) for the cast suggestion.